# Nginx config for craft working for everything but admin url's

Tags: routing

I am trying to configure NGINX to serve a craft 2 site.  I am getting the requests being routed through `index.php` for template url's but not for any admin routes which are redirecting to `index.php?p=/admin/**/*`.

I am assuming this has more to do with my NGINX config than craft as I have the following option enabled:

`'omitScriptNameInUrls' => 'true',`

Is there any craft related reason that admin URL's would redirect that way whereas template url's wouldn't?

here is my nginx config:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

server_name _;

error_log  off;
access_log off;

root /code/public;

charset utf-8;


location / {
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

# Disable reading of Apache .htaccess files
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

# Misc settings
sendfile off;
client_max_body_size 100m;

# 404 error handler
error_page 404 /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Update:

just deployed this same app to AWS elastic beanstalk and am running into the same issue with Apache.  This leads me to think maybe it's not related to nginx?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding specific location for admin & cpresources in the nginx config

```
location ^~ /admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ^~ /cpresources {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

before

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
```